# Refresh /dev/sdx list

Tags: linux, kernel, hard-drive, device

I've been messing around with my storage array (in that case 2xMD3000 SAS) and between the scans/rescans/delete/add my /dev/sdx block devices are all messed up.
Some of them are non existent and using fdisk on them gives:

> fdisk: unable to open sdc: No such device or address

It's not a real problem as I'm using `/dev/disk/by-id/wwn-xxxxx` anyway, but I would like to know if there is a way to trigger the kernel into updating/removing those empty and broken devices somehow.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the command:

`rescan-scsi-bus.sh --remove --issue-lip`

to have this nice and tidy script handle the work for you.

Comment: Thanks for that :) Didn't know such script was on my system

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/host0/scan
```

For the last command check which scsi controller you are using, host0 , host1 etc.